# ASP.NET MVC 4 Background operations

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, background, signalr

I am looking for nice and elegant architectural solution for ASP.NET MVC 4 Background operations.

My goal is developing some world that lives its own life and clients can only interact with it. For now let's say that it will be a simple clock and clients can watсh on it.

Now I have WebBackrounder + SignalR packages.

WebBackrounder:

```
[assembly: PostApplicationStartMethod(typeof(WebBackgrounderSetup), "Start")]
[assembly: ApplicationShutdownMethod(typeof(WebBackgrounderSetup), "Shutdown")]
namespace LibcanvasStudy.App_Start
{
    public static class WebBackgrounderSetup
    {
        static readonly JobManager _jobManager = CreateJobWorkersManager();
        public static RedrawJob RedrawJob { get; private set; }

        public static void Start()
        {
            _jobManager.Start();
        }

        public static void Stop()
        {
            _jobManager.Stop();
        }

        public static void Shutdown()
        {
            _jobManager.Dispose();
        }

        private static JobManager CreateJobWorkersManager()
        {
            RedrawJob = new RedrawJob(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            var manager = new JobManager(new[] { RedrawJob }, new JobHost());
            return manager;
        }
    }
```

RedrawJob while its execution rise event and SignalR hub catches it:

```
public class CanvasHub : Hub
{
    public CanvasHub()
    {
        if (WebBackgrounderSetup.RedrawJob != null)
            WebBackgrounderSetup.RedrawJob.Executing += (sender, args) => Request(args);
    }

    public void Request(RedrawEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Clients.All.redraw(...);
    }   
}
```

I have one main problem for now - How I can dynamicaly add and remove jobs from my JobManager?

Also I don't like this job-event system, it's a little bit awkwardly for me. Any proposal?

Comment: Before you continue in this direction I would recommend you reading this blog post: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx Hopefully after reading it you will no longer want to be implementing any background tasks in your web application.

Comment: I actually read it before wrote this code. That's why I decided to use WebBackgrounder.

Comment: I hope you won't use it in your web application though.

Comment: How about MVC app combined with WCF duplex service?

Comment: It doesn't really matter what you combine your MVC application with as long as you have background operations in it. The correct way is to move those operations in a separate process (maybe a Windows Service).

Answer (score 1):

What darin says is correct, but it can be worked around. For example what I do for these kind of scenarios is to have a internal WCF service that handles all jobs, you call it from the schedular or workflow engine using net.tcp or memory pipe. This way you benefit from all IIS sugar coating. And dont need to marshal your threads and error handing.

Second, implement some kind of event bus to decouple SignalR and your domain logic.

I have written this little lib that proxies between domain events and SignalR
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy

Install using nuget

```
Install-Package SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy
```

Please look at the wiki for the few easy steps required to hook it up
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/wiki

For a super lightweight in process event bus look at Caliburn.Micros EventAggregator
http://nuget.org/packages/Caliburn.Micro.EventAggregator/

Comment: What do think about using this code in any part of MVC app?

`IHubContext hub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<CanvasHub>();
hub.Clients.All.redraw(redrawData);`

Comment: I think its bad because it couples you to SignalR, but at the same time it looks like its very UI oriented (CanvasHub) so maybe its OK in this case., Still I think its good pratice to seperate concerns like this

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about using this code in any part of MVC app?

```
IHubContext hub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<CanvasHub>();
hub.Clients.All.redraw(redrawData);
```